# Show that if $A\in\mathbb R^{m \times n}$ has a full column rank then $A^TA$ is symmetric positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I know from the full column rank property that we can say the $\mbox{rank}(A)=n$. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

For symmetric you need to show that $(A^TA)^T = A^TA$.

For positive definite, notice $x^T A^T A x = \|Ax\|^2$.

Comment: To show symmetry, I've got that it's just $(A^TA)^T=A^T(A^T)^T=A^TA$. But the positive definite part is confusing me. I don't see how I'm supposed to use the $rank(A)=n$.

Comment: If $x\in \Bbb{R}^m$ is such that $x\neq 0$ the full rank property tells us that $Ax\neq 0$

Comment: So then I can use the full rank property of $A$ to say that $A^TA$ is also full rank. And therefore $A^TAx\neq0$. And then $x^T\neq0$ also so I can multiply by $x^T$ to find $x^TA^TAx\neq0$.